# ASP.Net Core Docker container can not find Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I'm trying to Dockerize my entire web app, and I'm starting with the backend. The server is an ASP.Net Core 2.2 web API, with a PostgreSQL database. However, try as I might, I cannot get the backend up and running.

As far as I can tell, the PostgreSQL db is not the issue. I can access it on the local machine once it's up, and I can enter it to ensure the correct db and user are there. But I keep getting the following error from the ASP server after waiting for docker-compose to run:

```
Application startup exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
```

I've found next to no information on this error, though someone did suggest that it is due to the server not being able to find anything on the port provided, but I can't see how it can't.

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  webapi:
    image: 'webapi'
    container_name: 'webapi'
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      DB_CONNECTION: "Server=postgres;Port=5432;Database=asg;User Id=asgwebapi;Password=admin;"
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    networks:
     - webapp-network

  postgres:
    image: postgres
    container_name: 'postgres'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "asgwebapi"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "admin"
      POSTGRES_DB: "asg"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - webapp-network

networks:
  webapp-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile for the server:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY Core/Core.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish Core/Core.csproj -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/Core/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Core.dll"]
```

I'm using Npgsql on the server, which is why those connections strings are set like that. I'm still a bit confused as towards what the "Server" field should be set to. Most examples have it set to be the same as the name for the Postgres container, but that fixes no issues for me. And while I don't necessarily need to connect to the Postgres container from the host, I know that I can't unless "Server" is set to localhost.

The server immediately fails upon start, as it looks for the database to populate with test data and run migrations, but it always has the same "Connection refused" error that I cannot get around. Currently, I can use Postgres through the cli with:

```
docker exec -it postgres psql dbname=asg asgwebapi
```

and I can also connect to the db and run the server locally, without issue. So not sure why the Docker container for the server can't find it, if that's even the issue.

Comment: You don't need `ports:` and `- "5432:5432"` for the `postgres` container unless you are wanting to connect to it from the host - although I appreciate that is useful for testing. Also remove all the networking stuff (the definition at the bottom and the `networks` per container, each container will be put on a default network automatically).

Comment: I don't really know Microsoft images, but can you shell into `webapi`? If so, perhaps you can run a `psql` client there to connect to the database container.

Comment: @halfer The ports were just there for testing, as it was easy to make sure the correct user was actually getting created. The networking was items copied from a tutorial, but I'll remove them. As for shelling into webapi, that should be my own image, defined in the Dockerfile, no? I'm quite new to Docker, so maybe I have that wrong. Because it immediately exits with a 139, I could try to stop it from running the server, and then enter the container. That might be better.

Comment: Ah, so your webapi container gets a connection refused, and that is a fatal error, so the server in that container crashes and exits?

Comment: To debug this, you could perhaps swap the `ENTRYPOINT` line for a long-running task (e.g. just a sleep) and then shell into the container to debug it. I assume from there you can try to start the server, and adjust settings/code so it does not crash. Although those changes will be lost when you restart the container, it will help you discover what you need to fix in your Dockerfile.

Comment: @halfer Yes, sorry I didn't make that clear. I'll try doing that.

Comment: I would also recommend adding some form of try/catch over your database connection code. A database being unavailable should never bring down your web server.

Comment: @halfer I know, though at the same time, this is just an API. The API without a DB doesn't have any more value than a crashed API at the simple end of things. Somehow though, the server now works. I'm not sure what I did to be honest. SSH'd into the server while it slept, realized it could curl postgres:5432, so started it up again and it worked. Not a single clue what I touched.

Comment: Sure, but you should be able to return a 500 HTTP response code with an `{"error": "Database down"}` to your calling client.

Comment: @halfer Pressed enter too quickly on that last message, but somehow got it working. Thanks for your help, it must've been that networking stuff you told me to delete.

Comment: Could be! No worries. Perhaps "bridge" was the wrong network type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered in the comments that the web server container started working again. We surmised that the custom network may have been at fault.

A good rule of thumb with containers is that if they are all on the same network in a Docker Compose file, they probably do not need to be on a custom network. By default, Docker Compose will put all containers on the same network, and they can contact each other already, using automatic DNS entries matching their service names.

Custom networks are most helpful if you would rather that some or all services should only be able to see a subset of the other services (or none at all). This can be useful for security reasons.

You can also create networks of non-standard types, but most users do not need these. More information [is available in the manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/extend/plugins_network/).